# when i'm trying to pass basic authentication then my code give me illegal argument exception

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have the below code

```
String userName = "xyz.com";
String password = "xyz.com";
URL url = new URL("http://....")
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
String userpass = userName + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic "
    + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
System.out.println("basic auth-->" + basicAuth);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization: ", basicAuth);

InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

int numCharsRead;
char[] charArray = new char[1024];
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
    sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
}
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println("*** END ***");
```

and exception is

```
basic auth-->Basic flkja44dsfaj=
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header value: Basic aHVuZ2FtYS5jb206aHVuZ2FtYS5jb20=

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.checkMessageHeader(HttpURLConnection.java:482)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.isExternalMessageHeaderAllowed(HttpURLConnection.java:434)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:2753)
at com.hungama.bbc.domObject.ContentDOMObjects.main(ContentDOMObjects.java:49)
```

Comment: what is the original your tried to encode? ~Y#k?

Comment: Your user name and password may not be matched!! Please check again.

Comment: Where is the class `Base64` coming from?

Comment: Don't put `:` in the request property key.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way to encode username and password:

```
final String userpass = userName + ":" + password;
final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

And you should remove ':' from field name of request property:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Comment: The `NO_WRAP` option did it for me, thanks. Mind explaining what that option does? I suspect the original problem was with the user/password containing the dot (.) symbol.